# How to put a multi level XML in 1 table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have an XML file in C:\data.xml

The XML looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<diseaseset>
     <diseases source="intuitive">
          <disease name="Asthma">
                <doc judgment="Y" id="3"/>
                <doc judgment="N" id="5"/>
                <doc judgment="N" id="7"/>
                <doc judgment="Y" id="9"/>
          </disease>
          <disease name="CAD">
                <doc judgment="Y" id="3"/>
                <doc judgment="Y" id="4"/>
                <doc judgment="N" id="6"/>
                <doc judgment="N" id="9"/>
          </disease>
    </diseases>
   <diseases source="textual">
          <disease name="Asthma">
                <doc judgment="N" id="1"/>
                <doc judgment="N" id="2"/>
                <doc judgment="N" id="8"/>
                <doc judgment="N" id="9"/>
          </disease>
          <disease name="CAD">
                <doc judgment="N" id="2"/>
                <doc judgment="Y" id="4"/>
                <doc judgment="N" id="5"/>
                <doc judgment="N" id="9"/>
          </disease>
     </diseases>
</diseaseset>
```

I want to put this in a table in this format

```
Source      Name    Judgment   ID
---------------------------------
intuitive   Asthma  Y          3
intuitive   Asthma  N          5
intuitive   Asthma  N          7
intuitive   Asthma  Y          9
intuitive   CAD     Y          3
intuitive   CAD     Y          4
intuitive   CAD     N          6
intuitive   CAD     N          9
....
```

I tried with this query but it did not work

```
DECLARE @x xml
 
SELECT @x = C
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\data.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS X(C)
            
DECLARE @hdoc int
    
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @x

SELECT source, name, judgment, id
FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/diseaseset/diseases/disease/doc' , 3)
WITH(
    id varchar(100),
    judgment VARCHAR(100)
    name VARCHAR(100)
    source VARCHAR(100)
    )
```

but the results always give null for name and source columns

how to fix that?

Comment: Your XML in invalid - the opening `<diseaseset>`, `<diseases>` and also `<disease>` nodes don't have any matching closing tags.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
    DiseasesSource = xc.value('(../../@source)', 'varchar(50)'),
    DiseasesName = xc.value('(../@name)', 'varchar(50)'),
    Judgement = xc.value('@judgment', 'varchar(50)'),
    Id = xc.value('@id', 'int')
FROM
    @x.nodes('/diseaseset/diseases/disease/doc') AS XT(XC)
```

I'd **strongly** recommend using this native, built-in XQuery support over the old, legacy, problem-plagued `OpenXml` stuff......

You'll get a result something like this:

| DiseasesSource | DiseasesName | Judgement | Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| intuitive | Asthma | Y | 3 |
| intuitive | Asthma | N | 5 |
| intuitive | Asthma | N | 7 |
| intuitive | Asthma | Y | 9 |
| intuitive | CAD | Y | 3 |
| intuitive | CAD | Y | 4 |
| intuitive | CAD | N | 6 |
| intuitive | CAD | N | 9 |
| textual | Asthma | N | 1 |
| textual | Asthma | N | 2 |
| textual | Asthma | N | 8 |
| textual | Asthma | N | 9 |
| textual | CAD | N 2 |  |
| textual | CAD | Y | 4 |
| textual | CAD | N | 5 |
| textual | CAD | N | 9 |